# Jackson Unable to find property 'xxx' on class: yyy

Tags: java, jackson, yaml

I am trying to use Jackson to parse a YAML file into an object, using the following code:

```
yaml.loadAs(userFilterConfigInputStream, UserFilterConfiguration.class);
```

I get the following error:

> Unable to find property 'xxx' on class: com.yyy...

I don't understand though, because my constructor seems clear:

```
public UserFilterConfiguration(
        @JsonProperty("groups") List<String> groups)
```

I have tried replacing `List<String>` by `String` or `String[]`, I still got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to make it work by replacing `yaml.loadAs...` by

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
userFilterConfig = mapper.readValue(configFile, UserFilterConfiguration.class);
```